# using jquery POST for an instant messaging system

Tags: jquery

the client posts info to the server like session cookies, csrf tokens and the content of any message it wants to send using jquery then the server sends back the messages and the client updates the page

it's super easy to code but would it work if too many people used it once?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially no.

It would be acceptable for a few users although not really ideal however, it wouldn't scale well. Say 100 people use your messaging system, each one sending an HTTP request whenever they check for new messages your server would be receiving tens of thousands of requests per minute.

You should really use socket connections because once connected, the requests sent between the client and the server don't include headers which makes them much less-data heavy.

This may be relevant https://blog.feathersjs.com/http-vs-websockets-a-performance-comparison-da2533f13a77